# How to update a field in nested array(two level at least)

Tags: mongodb

the document is(I have simplified the structure):

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("561f7896d3e4d2d8a6406baa"),
        "array" : [ 
            {
                "array" : [ 
                    {
                        "taskId" : 1,
                        "finished" : false
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to update the finished to true.
The query is

```
db.getCollection('JustTest').find({"array.array.taskId":1})
```

I tried `db.getCollection('JustTest').update({"array.array.taskId":1},{$set:{"array.$.finished":true}})`.But the result is

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("561f7896d3e4d2d8a6406baa"),
        "array" : [ 
            {
                "array" : [ 
                    {
                        "taskId" : 1,
                        "finished" : false
                    }
                ],
                "finished" : true
            }
        ]
    }
```

And `"array.$.array.$.finished":true` is illegal and returns error msg.

I have read http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/ .I also found a similar question [How to update data in nested array in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401893/how-to-update-data-in-nested-array-in-mongodb) but the answer is maybe naive.

I have no idea to update field in the nested array.Fix the position is not a good idea because the arrays(inner or outer) may be pushed or popped(from middle).making two collection can work but query will be difficult.

Comment: also related info: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/mongodb-user/78Gqs_GWiYE

Comment: @chridam the answer use two fix position and only one `$` because the desc of question knows the first two position. :)

Comment: @Tim Thank you but still no help.See the last line of my question.

Comment: I know it's not what you want to hear, but there's still no good way to do this and the linked duplicates cover the options.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thank you Johnny.I solved it by dimension reduction.I add an id field to inner array and remove the outer array so there is no nested array any more. : )